# Why can't I make a visible movieclip?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, adobe

I'm trying to make just a simple square movieclip show up on my stage, and it seems like nothing I've tried works...nothing appears on the stage! My code:

```
       var mc:MovieClip = new MovieClip();
        mc.x = 0;
        mc.y = 0;
        mc.width = 200;
        mc.height = 200;
        mc.opaqueBackground = 0xCCCCCC;

        // new ColorTransform object
        var obj_color:ColorTransform = new ColorTransform();
        // setting the new color we want (in this case, blue)
        obj_color.color = 0x0000ff;
        // applying the transform to our movieclip (this will affect the whole object including strokes)
        mc.transform.colorTransform = obj_color;

        this.stage.addChild(mc);
        mc.x = 0;
        mc.y = 0;
```

Why isn't my movieclip appearing on the stage?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your MovieClip contains nothing, so nothing is displayed. You are trying to cause the MovieClip to display a gray box by setting `width` and `height` and `opaqueBackground`, but unfortunately this doesn't work. `width` and `height` will only resize a clip that already has some content. If `width` and `height` are 0, then changing them has no effect, because trying to scale 0 results in 0. You can notice this by doing `trace(width)` after you set it to 200.

If you want to display a rectangle, use the [drawing API](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Graphics.html#drawRect%28%29) to draw it in the clip:

```
var mc:MovieClip = new MovieClip();
mc.x = 0;
mc.y = 0;
mc.graphics.beginFill(0xCCCCCC);
mc.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, 200, 200);
mc.graphics.endFill();
addChild(mc);
```